# Accessing data in array and setting rules for various outcomes

Tags: javascript, arrays, dice

I have a dice roll game that rolls a 6 sided die six times and puts the data into an array. it is in Javascript.

My question is how do I take the data in the array and add rules to it and output the total.

For example if I roll a 1 that equals 100 points. If I roll 2 1's double that score. If I roll 3 of any number add them together and multiply the total by 2.

I don't understand how to set these rules and output the results.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array for history, like this:

```
//empty array is the initial history
var history = [];
```

Then, let's suppose that you have rolled the dice and have a value. You can add it to history, like this:

```
history[history.length] = value;
```

You can check history against a pattern, like this:

```
history.join(',') === '2,3,4,1,1,6'
```

This is how you count an element:

```
var foo = history.join('');
console.log(6 - foo.replace(new RegExp("1", 'g'), ''));
```

As you can see, you can easily add rules to your game. You only need to believe that you can do it and to actually try to achieve your goal.